# equivalent body force

Tags: seismology

I am currently reading "Introduction to seismology second edition, and I can't wrap my head around earthquake sources, especially equivalent body force.

What is an “equivalent body force” and how is it justified? Are there any examples of force
systems that are frequently used to interpret seismograms and their real-world
equivalents. How the force systems are defined, how they operate and how they are mathematically represented??

Comment: Maybe this helps http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.915.6064&rep=rep1&type=pdf